# Ruby on Rails: dependent object destroyed when transfered from guest user to registered user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Here is my problem:

I'm using [Devise's guest_user](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user), that contains a logging_in method to transfer guest_user parameters to the registered user when he logs in. So in my case, the user `has_many periods, dependent: :destroy`, so here is the logging_in method:

```
def logging_in
  guest_periods = guest_user.periods.all
  guest_periods.each do |p|
    p.user_id = current_user.id
    p.save!
  end

  current_user.latest_entry = guest_user.latest_entry
  current_user.is_in_zone = guest_user.is_in_zone
  current_user.save
end
```

However, when a guest_user logs in, his periods gets destroyed instead of being transfered. Here is the log:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-05-11 00:18:03 +0300
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 24]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 23]]
  Period Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "periods".* FROM "periods" WHERE "periods"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 23]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "periods".* FROM "periods" WHERE "periods"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 23]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE "periods" SET "user_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "periods"."id" = $3  [["user_id", 24], ["updated_at", "2015-05-10 21:18:03.863162"], ["id", 170]]
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "is_in_zone" = $1, "latest_entry" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["is_in_zone", "t"], ["latest_entry", "2015-05-04"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-10 21:18:03.875572"], ["id", 24]]
   (15.8ms)  COMMIT
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "periods" WHERE "periods"."id" = $1  [["id", 170]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 23]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
```

So we can see that the transfer is done, but then in the end, the periods are destroyed anyway. They should not be, as they are not belonging to the user to be destroyed any more.

Why is it happening?

Comment: Not familiar with the gem but maybe you can try dup (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/dup) the periods and assign the new ones to the current_user as a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `Period#user_id` has changed, `guest_user.periods` is still loaded in memory and is what gets destroyed when you destroy the guest user. If you `guest_user.reload`, its associations will clear out and it becomes safe to destroy. You could also `guest_user.periods(true)` to force reload of just the periods.

Another option is:

```
guest_user.periods.update_all(user_id: current_user.id)
```

This executes a single query to perform the update, which will be nice if there are a lot of periods, and also doesn't load the `guest_user.periods` association, so it will load fresh during the destroy and find the correct empty set.